# Как правильно получить время?

Tags: java, android, дата

Использую библиотеку `Volley`, получаю с сервера дату в виде строки

```
"RecievedDate" : "2017-08-10T10:50:13.217",
```

Сразу делаю парс вот таким образом

```
@JsonProperty("RecievedDate")
private Date mReceivedDate = new Date();
```

И когда проверяю в дебагере, то эта дата выглядит вот так

```
Thu Aug 10 13:41:12 GMT+03:00 2017
```

Тут видно, что по не понятной причине было прибавлено вот это количество часов `GMT+03:00`, с сервера я получаю 10 часов , после парса у меня 13...

Подскажите как сделать, чтоб если я получаю 10 то после парса было тоже 10...

Comment: Дата приходит без указания таймзоны, поэтому парсер считает её как UTC. А в дебагере вы видите дату в вашей локальной таймзоне. Вероятно вам нужно написать кастомный десериализатор, в котором указать локальную таймзону для приходящей даты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решил вот так

```
final Date currentTime = new Date();

final SimpleDateFormat sdf =
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a z");

// Give it to me in GMT time.
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("GMT time: " + sdf.format(currentTime));
```

Спасибо @Edwin Buck

И вот ссылка

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236052/get-gmt-time-in-java

Comment: С таким подходом будут нестыковки, если ваше приложение запустится на устройстве с другой таймзоной. Лучше в десериализаторе вашего парсера явно указать в какой таймзоне приходит дата.